# Rowstore index on Clustered Columnstore - cardinality estimation mistake?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, columnstore

This one has me stumped. I have a dimension table with around 30 million rows in it. It is a clustered columnstore. Also, this table has a primary key constraint of type INT, on its surrogate key.

A query to retrieve the MIN() of the surrogate key, for a given date range, looks like this:

```
SELECT
    MIN(DIM.OrderId)
FROM
    dbo.Dim_Order AS DIM
WHERE
    DIM.OrderDate >= CAST('2016-06-01' AS DATE)
    AND DIM.OrderDate < CAST('2016-07-01' AS DATE)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Here is the output:

> Table 'Dim_Order'. Scan count 2, logical reads 833, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 1702561, lob physical reads 0,
>   lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'Dim_Order'. Segment reads 304001, segment skipped 0.
>
> (1 row affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 2829 ms,  elapsed time =
>   2876 ms.

Instead of using the columnstore, the optimizer is choosing to use the non-clustered primary key and perform Key Lookups through a Nested Loop. To make matters worse, it severely underestimates the number of rows returned.

**Strangely, the row estimate seems to be inversely proportional to the size of the date range.**

```
╔════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ Date Range ║ Estimated Number of Rows ║
╠════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 1 year     ║ 2.00311                  ║
║ 6 months   ║ 3.41584                  ║
║ 1 month    ║ 24.4459                  ║
║ 2 weeks    ║ 52.093                   ║
║ 1 week     ║ 99.9055                  ║
║ 3 days     ║ 217.632                  ║
║ 1 day      ║ 1088.16                  ║
╚════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

This version, with an INDEX hint, runs almost instantly:

```
SELECT
    MIN(DIM.OrderId)
FROM
    dbo.Dim_Order AS DIM WITH(INDEX=CCI_Dim_Order)
WHERE
    DIM.OrderDate >= CAST('2016-06-01' AS DATE)
    AND DIM.OrderDate < CAST('2016-07-01' AS DATE)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

> Table 'Dim_Order'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 1004, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'Dim_Order'. Segment reads 2, segment skipped 0.
>
> (1 row affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

I have observed this behavior on the following versions:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU5) (KB4040714) - 13.0.4451.0 (X64)

The repro script below will create an example table and populate it with 2 years of orders, for 2,000 customers, one order per day. This works out to 1,462,000 sample orders in our table, spanning 24 months, with each month having approximately 60,000 rows. The sample queries at the bottom of the script are intended to demonstrate the behavior. As you will see, for some reason, the row estimate is very low, and the optimizer refuses to use the clustered columnstore unless prompted.

I appreciate any input or advice on this. Here is the sample script.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Dim_Order

CREATE TABLE dbo.Dim_Order
    (
    OrderId INT NOT NULL
    , CustomerId INT NOT NULL
    , OrderDate DATE NOT NULL
    , OrderTotal decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
    );

WITH CTE_DATE AS
(
SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE) AS DateValue
UNION ALL
SELECT
       DATEADD(DAY, 1, D.DateValue)
FROM
       CTE_DATE AS D
WHERE
       D.DateValue < CAST('2017-12-31' AS DATE)
),
CTE_CUSTOMER AS
(
SELECT 1 AS CustomerId
UNION ALL
SELECT
       CustomerId + 1
FROM
       CTE_CUSTOMER AS D
WHERE
       D.CustomerId < 2000
)
, CTE_FINAL
AS
(
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateValue ASC, CustomerId ASC) AS OrderId
    , CustomerId
    , DateValue AS OrderDate
    , CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(100-1)+1, 2) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS OrderTotal
FROM
    CTE_DATE
    CROSS JOIN CTE_CUSTOMER
)
INSERT INTO
    dbo.Dim_Order
    (
    OrderId
    , CustomerId
    , OrderDate
    , OrderTotal
    )
SELECT
    ORD.OrderId
    , ORD.CustomerId
    , ORD.OrderDate
    , ORD.OrderTotal
FROM
    CTE_FINAL AS ORD
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI_Dim_Order ON dbo.Dim_Order;

ALTER INDEX CCI_Dim_Order ON dbo.Dim_Order
    REORGANIZE
    WITH (COMPRESS_ALL_ROW_GROUPS = ON)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Dim_Order
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Dim_Order PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (OrderId ASC);

RETURN;

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT
    MIN(DIM.OrderId)
FROM
    dbo.Dim_Order AS DIM
WHERE
    DIM.OrderDate = CAST('2016-06-01' AS DATE)
    AND DIM.OrderDate < CAST('2016-07-01' AS DATE)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

SELECT
    MIN(DIM.OrderId)
FROM
    dbo.Dim_Order AS DIM WITH(INDEX=CCI_Dim_Order)
WHERE
    DIM.OrderDate >= CAST('2016-06-01' AS DATE)
    AND DIM.OrderDate < CAST('2016-07-01' AS DATE)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Comment: I exprerimented a lot with CCIs + RIs and considering not to use it for a while... Performance is very inconsistent. I think this technology is not mature yet. Check each CU for SQL 2016 - how many bug fixes they have for columnstore. If you still need to use it - may be query hints is only option. Also try partitioning.

Comment: @Anton thank you for your feedback. One other aspect here is that if you bring another column in to aggregate, such as a date or something from the columnstore, that is not featured in a rowstore index, then the optimizer goes back to using the columnstore, and the query runs in a few milliseconds. Somehow, the mere presence of the rowstore causes this behavior, but not for all of my tables - only this particular one so I wonder if it's a tipping point in the optimizer, or a mistake in the math (division instead of multiplication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical [row goal](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals) cardinality estimation problem. You can add `USE HINT ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL')` to disable the row goal and should find the clustered column store is now costed cheaper and selected.

The plan has an ordered scan on `PK_Dim_Order` - as it is processing rows in order of `OrderId` and is looking for `MIN(DIM.OrderId)` it can stop as soon as it finds the first one matching the predicate on `OrderDate` - it assumes the 60,000 rows matching the month predicate will be scattered evenly throughout the index. In fact they are all in a contigous range with Ids `304001` to `364000`.

This assumption of non correlation is also why the estimated number of rows goes down as the date range gets bigger. If you double the number of matching rows for the date predicate and they truly were scattered evenly through the index you would only need to read half as many rows before hitting one matching both predicates and stopping the scan.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to solve this without hints, given that this system takes a wide variety of queries from an array of reporting tools? Also, at one point the segment alignment for this date column was 100% (built clustered columnstore from clustered index with MAXDOP 1). Despite being able to eliminate 19 of 20 segments (give or take, depending upon sample data set), it still would not use the columnstore.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA - there is trace flag 4138 but that will disable row goals for all queries on the system so you may find causes more problems than it solves with plan regressions

Comment: and it doesn't use the columnstore even with the segment elimination because it estimates that the rowstore plan will be so cheap - `0.0106137` cost because of the rowgoal adjustments

Comment: This is a fantastic, and very clear, explanation. I appreciate your time. This is what makes StackOverflow so great. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that there's a middle ground between a CCI with a PK, and a CI with NCCI.  That is a CCI with a unique index with included columns.  eg create unique index pk_order on DIm_Order(OrderId) include (OrderDate)

Comment: that would get rid of the lookup and so may way well be enough to resolve the perf issue here. Cc. @PittsburghDBA

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks to both of you! The unique index approach definitely works. It's still not as blazing as the columnstore, but I like it because it doesn't require the hints.